# IAR embedded workbench error - The file is too large to open in editor

Tags: ide, iar

I am using the IAR embedded workbench and getting this error each time i try to get to a definition of a function.
That by pressing right-click and then "Go to Definition of '(function_name)'"
Some function do get me to their definitions.
But some don't.
Help me please solve this issue.

Version: Arm 8.30.1

Error: The file is too large to open in editor

Comment: How large is the file you are trying to open?